# Valores randomicos para um exercicio Java

Tags: java

Estou querendo fazer um aplicativo de exercicio de soma, ele deve fazer uma busca no banco de dados aonde vai estar cadastradas os 3 valores(val1, val2, resto) como faço essa busca no banco ser aleatoria???

Comment: Bem vindo ao Stack Overflow em Português! Sua pergunta parece ter alguns problemas e sua experiência aqui no Stack Overflow em Português poderá não ser a melhor por causa disto. Queremos que você se dê bem aqui e consiga o que quer, mas para isso precisamos que você faça sua parte. Veja algumas orientações que vão te ajudar: [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8045) ([versão curta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8089/101)). Se a ajuda for muito simples ainda é possível fazer nos comentários.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Se você estiver usando números como primary key, você pode usar `java.util.Random#nextInt(int)` para gerar um número aleatório e fazer uma busca no banco baseado nesse número que `nextInt(3)` retornou.

Comment: Acho que no caso dele, ele vai ter que buscar os dados do banco, gerar este número randômico e recuperar o índice da lista correspondente ao número randômico

Comment: eu testei java.util.Random#nextInt(int) porem eu vou salvar operções como 1+1 = 2 e mandar esses valores pro programa ae eu quere que esses dados sejam buscados aleatoriamente no banco